# Linq2Sql : always perform LEFT JOIN even if single record is returned

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, orm

I'm using Linq2Sql (my customer is stuck on 3.5 so I can't migrate to entity framework) to access a SQL Server DB.

To improve performances in some cases, i've appended LoadOptions to my context. 
As I use compiled queries, i can't disable it, neither when they are useless and they slow down requests.

But sometimes I would like to retrieve data exactly just like if there is no LoadOptions appended to my context.

As a workaround, I tried to return not the full record but a projection of it.

Example :

```
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Product>(c => c.X);
dlo.LoadWith<Product>(c => c.Y);
context.LoadOptions = dlo;

return (from product in context.Products
        where ...
        select product).First();
```

This performs a query like :

```
Select product.*, X.*, Y.* from Product Left outer join X left outer join Y where....
```

In this case, all is perfectly normal.

My approach relies on something like this :

```
return (from product in context.Products
        where ...
        select new MyType() { p = product.Field }).First();
```

performs a query like

```
Select product.Field from Product ->Left outer join X left outer join
Y<-- where....
```

Please note the LEFT OUTER JOIN in the request.

While i was expecting something like :

```
Select product.Field from Product where....
```

So I would like to know if there is a way to avoid these joins ?

Thank you very much for you advice,

Comment: How are the tables X and Y related to table Product? Does a foreign key relationship exist between X and Product and Y and Product?

Comment: Yes, the foreign key to product is in X et Y.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog article](http://www.mrkwatkins.co.uk/Blog/2010/05/03/Improving-LINQ-To-SQL-Performance-Part-1---Changing-Load-Options) describes how to remove DataLoadOptions from a DataContext instance temporarily.

> you just need to change the value of the private loadOptions field on
>   your DataContext to change the load options

---

If you know the sql you want to send, you can skip the translation step and just use `DataContext.ExecuteQuery<Product>`

Comment: This is a great article, however I would like to avoid reflection or such like tricks. 
It is for an heavy load production application, and this kind of approach and (for example) the warn at the second part of the article (about compiled queries and object tracking) is a little frightening. 

As I also use CompiledQueries, LoadOptions, ObjectTracking... in the application, I had many difficulties to stabilize it despite only using "native" features of L2S...